# How to configure SMS Gateway integration in Magento locally?

Tags: magento2, integration, local

I am trying to configure SMS Gateway Integration in my local machine, but can't able to get proper guidance.

Anyone can help to fix that issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SMS Notification extension
User Manual**

[User Manual](https://magecomp.com/media/Docs/Magento-2-SMS-Notification-Helpdoc-by-MageComp.pdf)

Comment: Thanks you your response